# Using LSTM model to train spatial inputs

Tags: long-short-term-memory

I have an $x$-$y$ plane, inside that plane I have 9 paths $(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_3)$. Each path is classified into one of the three classes $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$. Each path has 100 coordinates points i.e $((x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2), \dots, (x_n, y_n))$. Totally I have 1800 input coordinate points. Now I am interested in training the LSTM model in such a way that if I feed some test path $p_{10}$, the model should be supposed to predict which class it belongs to. This is my problem definition. Regarding this, I have some questions

1. First of all, is it necessary to use LSTM models to obtain a solution?
2. Are there any other simple models to attain a solution to this problem?
3. I did some literature surveys for this kind of problem using LSTM, they are having time has one of the parameters along with $(x_1, y_1, t_1)$.

The paper I have read is "A Single-Shot Approach Using an LSTM for Moving Object Path Prediction".

I am a beginner to sequence model neural networks. A link or examples to similar works is very much beneficial.

Comment: Hello. [Welcome to AI SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). [Ideally, each post contains 1 main question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/287113). What your main question in this case (so that we know what you're looking for)? By the way, the 3rd point is not a question, but a statement.

Comment: I am looking for answers/ suggestions for my first two questions.